# How to make my endpoint respond to a SQL Union of two models in FastAPI?

Tags: python, orm, fastapi, sqlmodel

I have two models in my API using FastAPI.
Model 1: Deposits (id, created_at, updated_at, value)
Model 2: Withdrawals(id, created_at, updated_at, value)

And I want to make an endpoint that returns the union of these two models as in SQL (one below the other).
Something like:
select id, created_at, updated_at, value from deposits
union
select id, created_at, updated_at, value from withdrawals

How to do this? Does anyone have any tutorials, examples or documentation to send me?

Comment: How about using `UNION` in your SQL query? It's impossible to say without you providing examples of what you're using and what you've tried.

Comment: Multiple inheritance? Please provide some code. Show what you tried and what the results were. Show exactly what you _want_ the results to be instead.